# How to escape ',' sign at command line?

Tags: perl

When I do in perl script ([source](https://github.com/KES777/Devel-DebugHooks)):

```
`perl -d:DebugHooks::DbInteract='s;e [\@DB::stack\,\@DB::goto_frames]' -e '1'`
```

The module gets two arguments:

```
s;e [\@DB::goto_frames\
\@DB::stack];
```

But I want to get only one:

```
s;e [\@DB::goto_frames,\@DB::stack];
```

How to escape ',' sign?

Answer (score 2):

<s>It's got to be your module splitting on the comma, not `perl` or the shell.</s>  Running the following under `bash`, I get only a single argument in `@ARGV`:

```
$ perl -w -E 'say join "\n", ("---", @ARGV, "---")' 's;e [\@DB::stack\,\@DB::goto_frames]'
---
s;e [\@DB::stack\,\@DB::goto_frames]
---
```

---

**Edit:**

I stand corrected.  It is being split on commas by `perl`, presumably to allow passing multiple arguments to a module, as I proved to myself by creating a module at `./Devel/DbInteract.pm` containing:

```
package Devel::DbInteract;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub import {
  say 'Received ' . scalar @_ . ' params:';
  say join "\n", @_;
} 

1;
```

and running the command:

```
$ PERL5LIB=. perl -d:DbInteract='s;e [\@DB::stack,\@DB::goto_frames]' -e ''
Received 3 params:
Devel::DbInteract
s;e [\@DB::stack
\@DB::goto_frames]
```

Judging by the source linked in the asker's answer, there does not appear to be any provision for escaping values or any other way to prevent this splitting.  Your options, then, would be to either work around it by `join`ing the params back together or submitting a patch to the `perl` source to add an allowance for escaping.

Comment: It should be perl, because of syntax: [`-d:MOD[=bar,baz]`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perl does not care about escaping: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/perl.c#L3240-L3264

the `-d` flag just add next as zero line number into the script:

```
use Devel::DbInteract split(/,/,q{s;e [\@DB::stack\,\@DB::goto_frames]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people advice me simple approach than patching perl. Just to use `=>` in my case:

```
`perl -d:DebugHooks::DbInteract='s;e [\@DB::stack => \@DB::goto_frames]' -e '1'`
```